# countToRandom() accepting parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

```
var rand;
var count = 0;

function gimmeRandom();
{

    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
    count++;
    return(gimmeRandom);
}

function countToRandom();
{
    var count;
    for(count = 1; count <= rand; count++)
 {
    console.log(count);
 }

}

console.log("counting to a random number");
gimmeRandom();
countToRandom();
console.log("counting to another random number");
gimmeRandom();
countToRandom();
console.log(there has been "+count+" random numbers");
```

So the help i need is to use this code but get countToRandom to accept a parameter and then count to that value supplied in the parameter.

Thank You,

Comment: Im sorry where is this semicolon behind the function name

Comment: Simply pass a number as an argument and use that value as a limit in the function like you do with `count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var rand;
    var count = 0;

    function gimmeRandom()
    {
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
      return(rand);
    }

    function countToRandom(rand,count)
    { 
      for(var i = 1; i <= rand; i++)
      {
       console.log(i);
      }
       count++;
       return(count);
     }

console.log("counting to a random number");
rand = gimmeRandom();
count = countToRandom(rand,count);
console.log("counting to another random number");
rand = gimmeRandom();
count = countToRandom(rand,count);
console.log("there has been "+count+" random numbers");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function countToRandom(count) {
    for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
}

countToRandom(15);
```

Comment: thank you for solution, I tried the solution but the error to the task im trying to complete says it expected countToRandom() to accept a parameter and count to the value supplied to the parameter. Thanks.

Comment: That is exactly what the above code does. The countToRandom function accepts the count variable as a parameter to the function, then uses a for-loop to 'count' (write to console) all values from 1 to count.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working. Just delete the semicolons and the `return-statement` in the first function.

**Shortened**

```js
var rand;
var count = 0;

function gimmeRandom() {
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  console.log("rand", rand);
  count++;
}

function countToRandom() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= rand; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

console.log("counting to a random number");
gimmeRandom();
countToRandom();
console.log("counting to another random number");
gimmeRandom();
countToRandom();
console.log("there has been " + count + " random numbers");
```